# How to get sessions by day, by userid (as custom dimension)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I can get sessions by user ID, but I'm having problems to select also date. So my end result would have 3 cols: date, userid, sessions (where sessions is the total number of sessions for that day).

Sessions by user id, missing the date column:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index=2) AS userId,
    sum(totals.visits) AS sessions,
FROM
  `ga-360-tvgo.76246634.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN "20200701" AND "20200723"
GROUP BY
  1
```

Expected result:

[image: -an]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply add it to your groups

```sql
SELECT
    date,
    (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index=2) AS userId,
    sum(totals.visits) AS sessions,
FROM
  `ga-360-tvgo.76246634.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN "20200701" AND "20200723"
GROUP BY
  1,2
```